# Prob. 26, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: Proof of $m^*\left(A\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*\left(A\cap B_k\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Here is Prob. 26, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Let $\left\{ E_k \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a countable disjoint collection of measurable sets. Prove that for any set $A$,
> $$
> m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right).
> $$

My Attempt:

> If there is a positive integer $k_0$ for which $m^* \left( A \cap E_{k_0} \right) = \infty$, then by the monotonicity of outer measure we have
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) &= m^* \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( A \cap E_k \right) \right) \\ 
> &\geq m^* \left( A \cap E_{k_0} \right) \\
> &= \infty,
> \end{align}
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) = \infty. 
> $$
> On the other hand, as $m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \in [0, \infty]$ for every positive integer $k$, therefore for every positive integer $n > k_0$, we have
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \geq m^* \left( A \cap E_{k_0} \right),
> $$
> and thus we also have
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*\left( A \cap E_k \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n  m^*\left( A \cap E_k \right) \\
> &\geq m^* \left( A \cap E_{k_0} \right) \\
> &= \infty,
> \end{align} 
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*\left( A \cap E_k \right) = \infty. 
> $$
> Thus our desired identity holds.

> So we assume that, for every positive integer $k$, the relation $m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) < \infty$ holds.

> By the countable subadditivity of outer measure (i.e. Proposition 3 in Royden), we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) &= m^* \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( A \cap  E_k \right) \right) \\
> &\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( A \cap  E_k \right). \tag{1} 
> \end{align}
> $$

> Let $n$ be any positive integer. Since the sets in the countable colection $\left\{ E_k \right\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ are (pairwise) disjoint measurable sets, so too are the sets in the finite collection $\left\{ E_k \right\}_{k = 1}^n$, and hence by Proposition 6 in Royden and the monotonicity of outer measure, we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) &= m^* \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( A \cap E_k \right) \right) \\
> &\geq m^* \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n \left( A \cap E_k \right) \right) \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right),
> \end{align}
> $$
> that is,
> $$
>  \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \leq m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right). \tag{2} 
> $$

> Since the right-hand-side of (2) is independent of $n$, therefore (2) holds for each positive integer $n$, and thus we can conclude that
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \\ 
> &\leq m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right). \tag{3} 
> \end{align}
> $$

> Finally, (1) and (3) together yield our desired identity.

Is this proof correct and clear enough? Or, are there any shortcomings in any part thereof?

PS:

> Since (2) holds for every positive integer $n$ and since the sequence $\left(  \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence (of non-negative real numbers), therefore we have
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \\
> &= \sup \left\{ \, \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \, \right\} \\
> &\leq m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right),
> \end{align} 
> $$
> because by (2) the (extended) real number $m^* \left( A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right)$ is an upper bound for the set $\left\{ \, \sum_{k=1}^n m^* \left( A \cap E_k \right) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \, \right\}$.

Comment: I would explain a little bit more the last inequality of (3)

Comment: @TitoEliatron can you please have a look at my post now? I've made some edits.

Comment: clear enough for me.